# Started to gain weight, some in abdominal region

Tags: workout

Last year I started bulking up because I was 58kgs and 186-187cm. 
Today I weight 73kgs. Even though I go to gym between 3 and 4 times per week, having sessions between 50 minutes and 1 hour and 30 minutes I can see that my stomach got bigger (it's not huge but it's noticeable, before it was *flat*).

Since the start of this year I don't eat anymore fast-food, also I have a month or so in which I haven't eat much sugar or drink soda at all.

My question is - what can I try in order to become flat again?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

That can be anything... I would start with visiting doctor, and asking for blood test. It is not complicated, and can save a lot of effort. Other then that - use diet, or at least write down what you are eating. Diet is key here. If that is not working for you - you have other problem, like lack of D3 vitamin - that is why initially I wrote about blood test.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what a large majority of the public thinks, there are no specific exercises that will give you a "flat stomach" or "six pack abs".  There are certainly exercises which will strengthen it, but not just make it appear.

The only true way is to reduce your body fat percentage, which pretty much means just lose weight.  To maintain the washboard abs look, you need to be under a certain body fat percentage, and just because you cannot see the abs does not mean they are not there or are weak, they are just hidden under a layer of fat (which is not necessarily a bad thing).

After a bulk phase, typically comes a leaning phase.  In the bulk phase you will likely gain both fat and muscle, and the target of the leaning phase is to get rid of the fat and as little of the muscle as possible.